# How to get top n rows with a max limit by group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5', 'C6', 'C7', 'C8', 'C9', 'C10'],
  ...:                    'B': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
  ...:                    'R': [9, 1, 7, 4, 3, 5, 2, 6, 8, 10]})
Out[3]: 
     A  B   R
0   C1  A   9
1   C2  A   1
2   C3  A   7
3   C4  B   4
4   C5  B   3
5   C6  B   5
6   C7  B   2
7   C8  C   6
8   C9  C   8
9  C10  C  10
```

column R is my rank column and I want to get the top 5 ranked items (column A), however, maximum of 3 items per group in column B can be selected.

I know I can do the following to select the top 5 ranked items

```
df.sort_values('R').head(5)
Out[10]: 
    A  B  R
1  C2  A  1
6  C7  B  2
4  C5  B  3
3  C4  B  4
5  C6  B  5
```

But this selects 4 items from group B. how can i restrict it to have only a maximum of 3 items per group selected? my resulting dataframe should look like this

```
    A  B  R
1  C2  A  1
6  C7  B  2
4  C5  B  3
3  C4  B  4
5  C8  C  6
```

Logic - item C6 is not selected as it is the 4th item of group B so the next available item to be selected is C8 which has the next best rank and does not breach the group limitation.

Comment: Didn't you say max of 3 items per group? Theres only 1 left for group A and C.

Comment: That's because the other 2 items in group A and C don't belong to the top 5. Logic is, first get top 5, then reduce to max of 3 per group

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can try with [`GroupBy.head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html)

```
new_df = df.sort_values('R').groupby('B', sort=False).head(3).head(5)
print(new_df)
```

---

```
    A  B  R
1  C2  A  1
6  C7  B  2
4  C5  B  3
3  C4  B  4
7  C8  C  6
```

Comment: Nice one, I'd do `groupby('B', sort=False)` just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

```
top = df.merge(
    df.groupby('B').R.nsmallest(3) # get the 3 top ranked rows for each group
        .reset_index('B'),
        # `nsmallest` will return a new df with B and df.index as MultiIndex
        # so we reset B to a column
        # however column A is not in this new df, so we merge with the original df
    how='right') # and drop any rows not in the new df
```

Output

```
     A  B   R
0   C2  A   1
1   C3  A   7
2   C1  A   9
3   C7  B   2
4   C5  B   3
5   C4  B   4
6   C8  C   6
7   C9  C   8
8  C10  C  10
```